# Runtime Error при запуске приложения

Tags: c++, runtime

При запуске одной игровой программы выскакивает ошибка данного рода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Дано:**

1. Win7 x86
2. Microsoft Visual C++ 2005, 2008, 2010

Также пробовал запуск от имени администратора, не помогло.
*Читал на форумах, что это "Должно" помочь*

Буду очень благодарен

Comment: >Также пробовал запуск от имени администратора, не помогло

крутой способ, ничего не скажешь

Comment: @DreamChild, Читал на форумах, что это "должно" помочь, поэтому уточнил. сразу.

Comment: вряд ли вам можно помочь. Потому что спросили вы примерно следующее: "У меня что-то не работает. Об остальном догадайтесь сами"

Comment: @DreamChild, можно попросить ваш скайп? Дабы там Вам все показать и уточнить.

Comment: @IamS бррррр...вы понимаете, что вам тут не помогут? В том числе и я? У вас же нет исходников этого приложения, не так ли? (а если бы и были, то вряд ли у кого-то возникло бы желание бесплатно в них ковыряться) Это ваше "Runtime error" может говорить о чем угодно, и мне оно говорит только о том, что "что-то не так". Я программист, а не экстрасенс, поэтому "лечить по фотографии" не умею. Вам нужно обратиться к разрабочику вашей чудо-программы, а не насиловать чужие мозги. 

И да, вы же как-то раз утверждали, что якобы разбираетесь в разработке игр? Так почему же не понимаете очевидных вещей?

Comment: @DreamChild, Нахомить Вам, чтоле..

Comment: я, по-вашему, в чем-то неправ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего не хватает какой либо dll.
При разработке приложения мог стоять Visual C++ 2010 prof или другой, который поставляется с собственными модулями.

Например такими:

```
"msvcp100.dll"  - 100 номер версии студии.
"msvcr100.dll"
```

А при запуске .exe на другом компьютере:

1. пути к этим dll не прописаны
2. прописаны неправильно
3. dll имеет иную версию и соответственно объявления вызываемых из dll функций с тем, что присутствует в .exe может различаться.
4. их вообще нет
5. DLL есть но еще не зарегистрированы в системе. Нужно перезагрузиться.

Поэтому все зависимые dll модули следует помещать в корневую папку приложения или копировать в папку system при установке.

Все остальные виды ошибок и способы их решения, исходя из имеющейся информации, определить невозможно.